# Apply Python Code To Sqlalchemy Filters

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to apply python code (like splitting a list) to a `sqlalchemy` filter. An example is as follows: my database stores a full name as a field in the table. I want to query my database for all people who have a given first name. So what I want to do is something like:

```
User.query.filter(User.name.split()[0].lower() == 'henry'.lower())
```

When I try to run this query, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.name has an attribute 'split'
```

What is the general way to apply python commands like `split()`, `lower()`, etc. to my `sqlalchemy` queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is constructing a SQL expression, not a Python expression.  You can apply SQL functions to the expression by using the [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) object.

```
from sqlalchemy import func
User.query.filter(func.lower(func.substring_index(User.name, ' ', 1)) == 'henry')
```